# append rows using pd.concat() with python from a 'for loop'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

After an update, I am getting the following message:

**'The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.'**

I am conducting an artificial star experiment, where I have three files with columns:

b1: ['Id', 'x', 'y', 'bmag'] - artificial stars with b-filter

i1: ['Id', 'x', 'y', 'imag'] - artificial stars with I-filter

biart: ['Id', 'x', 'y', 'bmag', 'imag'] - measured stars

**I have calculated the minimum radial distance between stars in b1 (artificial) and biart (measured) and writing a dataframe with the 'Id', 'bmag' and 'imag' if the minimum distance is satisfied. **

**The code goes through each row of b1 and determines which row of biart has minimum distance, then saves it in a dataframe**

**I am having trouble re-writing my code with *pd.concat()* instead of *df.append()*. Please help!**

```
extract = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Id_art', 'x_art', 'y_art', 
                                'bmag_art', 'imag_art', 
                                'dist_d',
                                'Id_meas', 'x_meas', 'y_meas',                                 
                                'bmag_meas', 'imag_meas'])

for i in range(len(b1.index)):
    
    x = b1['x'].iloc[i]
    y = b1['y'].iloc[i]
    
    dist = np.sqrt((x - biart['x'])**2 + (y - biart['y'])**2)
    
    if (min(dist))<=1/2:
            
        extract = extract.append({'Id_art': b1['Id'].iloc[i],
                                    'x_art':b1['x'].iloc[i], 
                                   'y_art': b1['y'].iloc[i], 
                                 'bmag_art':b1['bmag'].iloc[i],
                                 'imag_art':i1['imag'].iloc[i],
                                      'dist_d':min(dist), 
                            'Id_meas':biart['Id'].iloc[dist.idxmin()], 
                             'x_meas':biart['x'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
                             'y_meas':biart['y'].iloc[dist.idxmin()], 
                          'bmag_meas':biart['bmag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
                          'imag_meas':biart['imag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()]},
                                     ignore_index=True)
```

**I am new to python. Can you please help explain how to rewrite the code below to pd.concat()?**

```
extract.append({'Id_art': b1['Id'].iloc[i],
                  'x_art':b1['x'].iloc[i], 
                 'y_art': b1['y'].iloc[i], 
               'bmag_art':b1['bmag'].iloc[i],
               'imag_art':i1['imag'].iloc[i],
                 'dist_d':min(dist), 
                'Id_meas':biart['Id'].iloc[dist.idxmin()], 
                 'x_meas':biart['x'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
                 'y_meas':biart['y'].iloc[dist.idxmin()], 
              'bmag_meas':biart['bmag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
              'imag_meas':biart['imag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()]},
                                    ignore_index=True)
```

**please see below the first 30 values of the three data files:**

```
b1:
    Id       x         y      bmag    z1  z2  z3  z4  z5
      1    1163.630 1327.069  16.4552   0   0   0   0   0
      2    1747.045 1477.734  16.1293   0   0   0   0   0
      3    3236.084 1252.050  16.5628   0   0   0   0   0
      4    2516.600  888.832  17.7005   0   0   0   0   0
      5    1868.000 1376.218  16.3139   0   0   0   0   0
      6    2484.642  941.331  16.7632   0   0   0   0   0
      7    2984.336  640.185  16.1351   0   0   0   0   0
      8    2612.480 1664.341  16.3573   0   0   0   0   0
      9    1973.405  731.071  18.7704   0   0   0   0   0
     10    3391.978  130.435  16.1769   0   0   0   0   0
     11     165.021  942.634  17.4829   0   0   0   0   0
     12    2491.430 1397.675  16.5589   0   0   0   0   0
     13    2886.291 1367.745  16.3339   0   0   0   0   0
     14     939.302  726.039  16.8744   0   0   0   0   0
     15    2296.265  686.110  16.1132   0   0   0   0   0
     16     682.263  932.721  16.5750   0   0   0   0   0
     17    2393.509 1776.220  16.8953   0   0   0   0   0
     18     277.072 1879.963  16.1769   0   0   0   0   0
     19    1824.305 1616.309  16.2134   0   0   0   0   0
     20    2986.818  833.414  16.2364   0   0   0   0   0
     21    2547.293 1067.399  16.4345   0   0   0   0   0
     22     707.099  591.125  16.1352   0   0   0   0   0
     23    1987.175  899.605  17.0269   0   0   0   0   0
     24    2853.484  761.114  16.4994   0   0   0   0   0
     25    2664.596  897.447  16.7100   0   0   0   0   0
     26     730.565  905.192  18.1313   0   0   0   0   0
     27    2760.565 1894.611  17.9226   0   0   0   0   0
     28    3427.851 1883.343  18.2891   0   0   0   0   0
     29    2165.442  769.363  17.9948   0   0   0   0   0
     30    2982.916 1094.855  17.1777   0   0   0   0   0
```

```
i1:
     Id       x         y      imag    z1  z2  z3  z4  z5
      1    1168.121 1332.597  15.1104   0   0   0   0   0
      2    1751.536 1483.263  14.3248   0   0   0   0   0
      3    3240.575 1257.578  15.3140   0   0   0   0   0
      4    2521.091  894.360  17.1246   0   0   0   0   0
      5    1872.491 1381.746  14.8184   0   0   0   0   0
      6    2489.133  946.859  15.6679   0   0   0   0   0
      7    2988.827  645.714  14.3458   0   0   0   0   0
      8    2616.971 1669.869  14.9122   0   0   0   0   0
      9    1977.896  736.599  18.6215   0   0   0   0   0
     10    3396.469  135.964  14.4787   0   0   0   0   0
     11     169.512  948.163  16.8041   0   0   0   0   0
     12    2495.921 1403.203  15.3067   0   0   0   0   0
     13    2890.782 1373.273  14.8621   0   0   0   0   0
     14     943.793  731.567  15.8544   0   0   0   0   0
     15    2300.756  691.638  14.2601   0   0   0   0   0
     16     686.754  938.249  15.3363   0   0   0   0   0
     17    2398.000 1781.748  15.8890   0   0   0   0   0
     18     281.563 1885.491  14.4787   0   0   0   0   0
     19    1828.796 1621.837  14.5791   0   0   0   0   0
     20    2991.309  838.942  14.6377   0   0   0   0   0
     21    2551.784 1072.927  15.0697   0   0   0   0   0
     22     711.590  596.653  14.3461   0   0   0   0   0
     23    1991.666  905.133  16.1022   0   0   0   0   0
     24    2857.975  766.643  15.1955   0   0   0   0   0
     25    2669.087  902.975  15.5765   0   0   0   0   0
     26     735.056  910.720  17.7406   0   0   0   0   0
     27    2765.056 1900.140  17.4449   0   0   0   0   0
     28    3432.342 1888.871  17.9612   0   0   0   0   0
     29    2169.933  774.891  17.5477   0   0   0   0   0
     30    2987.407 1100.383  16.3397   0   0   0   0   0
```

```
biart:
     Id      x       y      bmag         imag      
      1    3.463   964.699  16.0450     16.9640   
      2    5.084  1567.960  16.9260     18.4700   
      3    5.105   236.018  15.0720     16.1090   
      4    5.236   364.229  17.4830     15.8440   
      5    5.478  1434.603  17.3220     16.7400   
      6    5.564   453.920  16.9000     17.2100   
      7    6.015  1186.374  17.9310     15.5080   
      8    6.017   945.186  17.5790     17.2270   
      9    6.031  1001.720  15.4920     16.7710   
     10    6.337   747.211  16.0480     14.9890   
     11    6.376  1243.525  15.8780     14.8180   
     12    6.426   635.425  17.3890     17.2010   
     13    6.432    72.437  16.3430     16.7180   
     14    6.584   982.933  17.7750     17.9360   
     15    6.630   688.179  16.8100     17.2390   
     16    6.827  1559.448  17.6680     17.1000   
     17    6.855   502.682  18.0290     17.4950   
     18    7.260  1807.838  17.8060     17.3680   
     19    7.289   981.327  18.3170     17.6140   
     20    7.383  1485.190  16.4730     14.4650   
     21    7.461  1141.420  16.3860     15.6110   
     22    7.696  1213.424  15.9370     14.7050   
     23    7.779  1211.424  16.9000     15.2840   
     24    7.853   821.390  15.1270     16.2590   
     25    7.868  1325.808  18.3270     17.9500   
     26    7.954  1789.587  16.2340     14.7330   
     27    8.132   194.533  17.1350     16.5100   
     28    8.194  1390.519  16.3770     15.4670   
     29    8.555   299.428  17.7980     16.5920   
     30    8.724   982.512  17.9880     17.1510
```

[image: Extract output]

Comment: The code can be simplified a lot using vectorized operations. It will speed up the code too. Then you don't even need to use `append`.

Comment: Can you post b1, i1 and biart so we can reproduce the data? Even if it is only a small sample. Thanks. And, now that I read it again, maybe you need to just read the files into a dataframe as the first start? So you have three base dataframes to play with. Looping in pandas is always best to be avoided. That is what vishnudev is talking about.

Comment: I have edited my question and have included the first 30 rows of each file and an image of the output. Thank you in advance for your help! I really appreciate it

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you mean about using vectorized operations? and reading the csv files into a dataframe? I have been using this command to read files b1= pd.read_csv('b1.csv', sep=',')

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding rows to a dataframe, you can generate each dataframe from a single row and then concat all the rows.

Although it may surprise, it is more efficient.

`list_a = []`

for i in range(len(b1.index)):

```
x = b1['x'].iloc[i]
y = b1['y'].iloc[i]

dist = np.sqrt((x - biart['x'])**2 + (y - biart['y'])**2)

if (min(dist))<=1/2:
        
    list_a.append(pd.DataFrame({'Id_art': b1['Id'].iloc[i],
             'x_art':b1['x'].iloc[i], 
             'y_art': b1['y'].iloc[i], 
             'bmag_art':b1['bmag'].iloc[i],
             'imag_art':i1['imag'].iloc[i],
             'dist_d':min(dist), 
             'Id_meas':biart['Id'].iloc[dist.idxmin()], 
             'x_meas':biart['x'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
             'y_meas':biart['y'].iloc[dist.idxmin()], 
             'bmag_meas':biart['bmag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()],
             'imag_meas':biart['imag'].iloc[dist.idxmin()]},
             index=[0])``
```

now concat.

```
df_all = pd.concat(list_a, ignore_index=True)
```

and delete intermediate list

```
del list_a
```

Comment: I have tried the code otromas posted, but I am getting this "ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"

Comment: modified answer from index=None ==>   index=[0] Try now

Comment: I did try that, and it worked.  I am glad you could confirm. thank you! but what does the index=[0] mean? none?

Comment: In a Dataframe index=[ X ] is a list with the values ​​of that index of that Dataframe.

In the append, That DataFrame with a single row has a single index: 0

When the concat is done, the index of the whole DataFrame is recreated.

Comment: Is there another way to this besides using an empty list and appending? I realize that this takes significantly more time to run than when I was using my original code, specially when I just want to determine the minimum distance between stars and I have almost 40,000 in one file.

Comment: Please, open new question about performance. Put  execution time both scripts